# An Observable for the Current Activated Route?

Tags: angular, angular-router

For various purposes, it may be advantageous to attach a listener to the Router which is called every time the route changes. This could be used to trigger an AJAX call, for example.

Puzzlingly, the `route.params` observable and `route.url` observable do not update when the route changes, making them unsuited to this task.

Consider the following service,

```
@Injectable()
export class SagasService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route : ActivatedRoute, private router : Router ){
        Observable.combineLatest(
            route.params,
            route.url
        )
        .subscribe(([params,url])=>{
            console.log(params,url);
        });
        router.events.subscribe(e=>{
            Observable.combineLatest(
                 route.params,
                 route.url
             )
             .subscribe(([params,url])=>{
                 // the route changes... but this... it does not trigger
                 console.log(params,url);
             });
    }
}
```

In this example, **neither** of the subscribe calls are updated with new parameters. What is the correct way of subscribing to an ongoing picture of the router's state?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `route.params` and `route.url` seperately? `combineLatest` will only emit a value once all of the input observables have themselves emitted a value at least once, so it might be that only one of them is updating.

Comment: Thank you for the response, once they have both emitted once, combine latest will emit any time either of them emits. Moreover, subscribing to these values separately has the same problem.

Comment: This answer goes a long way to explaining this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880705/an-observable-for-the-current-activated-route

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you need to subscribe the router events,

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
Injectable()
export class SagasService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route : ActivatedRoute, private router : Router ){
// navigation start
       router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
            .subscribe(() => {
// add your logic here
});
//navigation ends here
 router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(() => {
// add your logic here
});


    }
}
```

the Navigation start event fires when the router initiated navigation from one route to another.
Navigation end event fires when the router navigation ends.
We can add our logic based on the requirement we have.
I hope it helps.

Comment: This is great, but inside the `subscribe` call, how do we access the current URL and parameters?

Comment: Also, the above code throws the error, `router.events.filter` is not a function without the required import (added to the example)

Comment: Before that you have to import 
import {NavigationCancel, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationStart, Router} from '@angular/router';

from angular router

Comment: For Getting params  import  activated route
  private route: ActivatedRoute,

and then
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((qp: any) => {
console.log(qp['xyx']);
});

this.route.params.subscribe((p: any) => {
console.log(p['xyx']);
});

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the `events` of `Router` and get the last child in the chain.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  NavigationEnd,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SagasService {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.route.snapshot),
        map((route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
          while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
          }
          return route;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
        console.log(route);
      });
  }
}
```